# Migration of Communities (napili template )

Tags: community, partner-communities

1)I have deployed the Napili template community into the sandbox through the ANT , when i click on the URL of the community it says URL does not exist , i deployed the site.com,network and custom sites ..

2)Can any one please provide me the steps to solve this issue ..did i missed anything in the deployment .

3) Do i need to execute any manual steps after the deployment of community

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried to "Publish" your community ?
Maybe it's the same "error" when you refresh your sandbox. You need to publish your community to make it work !

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: yes , i published it